# Wordpress custom image cropper widget

Tags: php, wordpress

The wordpress image editor isn't quite what I want it to be so I'm trying to create a plugin to fix it, ideally I would want to use the [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) library, altough I can't figure out how to change or create a custom widget that would take over the default one.

After searching around a bit I could only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114323/customizing-the-wp-image-editing-widget) Stack Overflow post about someone who rougly wanted to do the same only using the text editor, but the reply doesn't quite work for me since the cropper doesn't use TinyMCE plugin (I assume).

So I was hoping someone could provide some sources for me to continue on, i've hit a bit of dead end.

Comment: If you read the answer you will find its adding the tinymce button so its must help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114323/customizing-the-wp-image-editing-widget

Comment: @dipmala I'll take a look at it, but this means the Image cropper does use TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up using JavaScript to just overlay Croppie over the default WordPress image editor.

EDIT: My previous mentioned solution didn't work all that great so I ended up using acf-image-crop-add-on WordPress plugin and modifying that code, which worked out great for me